# svg path animate whole whole path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a simple path that animates with `from="0%" to="100%"`, but only a part of the path shows up. How can I animate from the beggining to the end of the path?

```
<svg>
    <path d="M100,100 S150,100 200,150 S150,150 100,200 S100,200 100,300 S200,300 300,300 S200,300 100,200 S100,200 100,300 S200,300 300,300 S315,300 330,200" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="100000,100000" id="foo">
        <animate xlink:href="#foo" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" fill="freeze" from="0%" to="100%"></animate>
    </path>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8g2k2cy4/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a way to it, maybe there are better ways...

So the svg `path` element has a `.getTotalLength();` method that returns the path length. This way I can apply/use that in the `animate` element via JavaScript like:

```
var animEl = document.querySelector('animate');
animEl.setAttribute('to', animEl.parentNode.getTotalLength());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8g2k2cy4/1/